# How to convert "javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec", DESKeySpec code to dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Im trying to implement security on an app using the DESKeySpec which is java. how can i use the code for dart

```
public String Encrypt(String value) throws Exception {
  SecureRandom sr=new SecureRandom();
  DESKeySpec dks=new DESKeySpec(getRowKey());
  SecretKeyFactory keyFactory=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
  SecretKey key=keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);
  Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("DES");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,sr);
  byte[] encryptedClassData=cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF8"));
  return new String(encryptedClassData,"UTF8");
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Unfortunately, the best crypto package for Dart (`pointycastle`) doesn't support DES, but does support AES. There is a DES Dart package (`tripledes`) but it doesn't support binary keys (it uses simple key strings). The good news is that you could easily branch tripledes and add binary keys.